# function as function argument - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I read that it is possible to pass a function as an argument. But now I have to test a given function and therefore use it and my question is: how do I give the function the arguments?

```
def bucketMap(key, M):
    return key*M

def bucketSort(a, bucketMap, d):
    N = len(a)
    M = int(N / float(d))  # Anzahl der Buckets festlegen

    # M leere Buckets erzeugen
    buckets = [[] for k in xrange(M)]

    # Daten auf die Buckets verteilen
    for k in xrange(len(a)):
        index = bucketMap(a[k].key, M) # Bucket-Index berechnen
        buckets[index].append(a[k])    # a[k] im passenden Bucket einfuegen

    # Daten sortiert wieder in a einfuegen
    start, end = 0, len(buckets[0])    # Anfang und Ende des ersten Buckets
    for k in xrange(M):
        insertionSort(buckets[k])      # Daten innerhalb des Buckets sortieren
        a[start:end] = buckets[k]      # Daten an der richtigen Position in a einfuegen
        start = end                    # Anfang und Ende fuer das naechste Bucket
        end += len(buckets[k])         #     aktualisieren
```

So let's say I now have an array a with my data I want to sort with bucketSort.
How do I call it?
I can't just say:

```
result = bucketSort(a, bucketMap(), d)
```

because I have to give arguments if I call `bucketMap()` in there, but I don't want to do that because it has to do `bucketMap()` for every element in `m` which is done in `bucketSort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass the return value of a function *call*, rather than the function *itself*, to `bucketSort`. Just use

```
result = bucketSort(a, bucketMap, d)
```

Incidentally, since `bucketMap` simply multiplies its arguments together, you don't need to define a new function; use `operator.mul` instead.

```
import operator
result = bucketSort(a, operator.mul, d)
```

If you really want a specific name (for readability), you can just make an assignment.

```
import operator
bucketMap = operator.mul
result = bucketSort(a, bucketMap, d)
```

Comment: Okay, when I tried it it didn't work out - probably because it was in a unittest. The compiler thought of bucketMap as a float.
My unittest looks like that:
`import unittest
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    a = createData(100) #creates array with 100 random numbers between 0 and 1
    result = bucketSort(a, bucketMap, 5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()`

Comment: The point of bucketMap looks quite useless now, but I have to add a better bucketMap later and it also gives the chance to edit bucketMap without having to look over bucketSort.
Still, if I had to chose I would simply put the needed multiplication into bucketSort. ;)

Comment: I continue to have the following error: **'float' objection has no attribute 'key'** no matter how I try to fix it. Any suggestions where this could come from?

Comment: What does `a` contain? Your code assumes that each element is an object with a `key` attribute, but clearly does not.

Comment: I missed your comment and found it out myself. Yes, the a[k].key must be a[k], the code I was given was therefore wrong... at some days it just takes forever until I recognize the most stupid errors.